# How to fix blank page on admin-post.php call?

Tags: php, wordpress

I just noticed that `admin-post.php` doesn't fired for me.

I have a simple form :

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" >
 <?php wp_nonce_field( 'customLoginConnect', 'customLoginConnectNonce' ); ?>
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="customLoginConnect" />
 <input class="form-control" type="email" name="user_email" required>
 <input class="form-control" type="password" name="user_pwd" required>
</form>
```

And this :

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_customLoginConnect', 'customLoginConnect' );
add_action( 'admin_post_customLoginConnect', 'customLoginConnect' );
```

When I submit this, I get blank page..

I have Wordpress 5.4.1 and I deactivate ALL my plugins and change theme.
I put `WP_DEBUG` as `true` and see no errors. Nothing !

I do something wrong ?

Comment: Can you describe what this form should do, what should happen on submit? You enter an email ... if this should become a login there will be a password needed.

Comment: I simplify the form for the question, it's a custom login form, I remove other field. The problem is admin_post is not fired !

Comment: Have you dumbed your action value to see if the url is correctly inserted? What is this customLoginConnect? Maybe this can have an impact for causing the white page (i.e. preventing the submit).

Comment: Yes, I have a : var_dump($_POST);die(); .
It doesn't even fire the function

Comment: You may try adding a an action parameter like `<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>?action=customLoginConnect` . maybe this answer is also worth a look https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177076/post-form-request-with-admin-post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is added to functions.php file

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_customLoginConnect', 'customLoginConnect' );
add_action( 'admin_post_customLoginConnect', 'customLoginConnect' );
```

The function definition is also added to the functions.php file.
Ex:

```
function customLoginConnect()
{
    //Please add your code here
    $url = $_POST['_wp_http_referer'];
    wp_redirect($url);
}
```

The error is usually caused by a filter or an action not properly declared. Can you please check this. Now you say you get a white page. This is because we need to redirect back to our form. I've used a simple wp_redirect(). Hope this will resolve your problem.